# .htaccess is not working for multiple urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?cslug=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ category.php?cslug=$1


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ location.php?lslug=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ location.php?lslug=$1
```

This is only working for `category.php`. How can I make this for both urls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will never work. You have to make two different Regex strings. For example: `RewriteRule ^cat-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?cslug=$1` `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ location.php?lslug=$1`

Comment: Agreed. You need something in the URL to differentiate which URL refers to a category and which to a location.

Comment: You haven't declared any `RewriteCond` statements or any other flags, so all your `RewriteRule`'s will be executed one after the other. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've two files category.php and location.php

if category.php?cslug=web-services then url should be www.example.com/web-services/

if location.php?lslug=mycity then  url should be www.example.com/mycity/

how to make this?

like php is there any if else condition in .htaccess